# JSR 303 Validator injection with Spring in Jersey classes

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I encountered a strange behaviour that I didn't manage to explain, with a validator injection in a Jersey class with DI managed by Spring.

To sumerize the situation :

I'm using Jeysey 2 and Spring 4 to produce REST web services using the jax-rs specification, and I'm validating the bean with the jsr303 bean validation annotations. The bean validation implementation is Hibernate Validator, bundled within jersey-bean-validation dependency.

Here is my POM:

```
<jersey.version>2.26-b07</jersey.version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring4</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In my spring configuration, I declare a Validator bean (with a custom message interpolator to retrieve the error messages in database), which I'll later want to inject in my web service classes :

```
@Bean
public Validator getValidator(MessageInterpolator messageInterpolator){
    return Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure()
            .messageInterpolator(messageInterpolator)
            .buildValidatorFactory()
            .getValidator();
}
```

At this point, I'm able to inject my validator in Jersey classes using the @Autowired annotation, but not with the jsr 330 @Inject annotation which inject another validator with the default Hibernate Validator message interpolator...

```
@Autowired
private Validator validator; // OK

@Inject
private Validator validator; // KO

@Inject
private OtherService otherService; // OK
```

Can you explain me what happen here ?

I understood that the dependency injection implementation bundled with Jersey is HK2, but the jersey-spring plugin is supposed to do the bridge between HK2 and Spring, I must have missed something because they seem completely dissociated, I think that :

- @Autowired use Spring and inject the bean I've defined
- @Inject use HK2 which is not aware of that bean, and inject the one found in the Hibernate Validator project...

By the way I'm perfectly able to inject my other Spring services with the @Inject annotation, that's why I'm loosing my mind and don't know what to think... The only problematic bean seems to be this Validator.

I also tried to use the @Valid annotation to validate my beans without having to inject the validator, and the problem is the same : Jersey use the default validator from Hibernate Validator...

---

After lots of time, I found a way to fix the @Valid problem by creating a ContextResolver Provider to modify Jersey default configuration with my custom message interpolator :

```
@Provider
public class ValidationConfigContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ValidationConfig> {

    private final MessageInterpolator messageInterpolator;

    @Inject
    public ValidationConfigContextResolver(MessageInterpolator messageInterpolator) {
        this.messageInterpolator = messageInterpolator;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationConfig getContext(Class<?> aClass) {
        final ValidationConfig config = new ValidationConfig();
        config.messageInterpolator(messageInterpolator);
        return config;
    }

}
```

Now Jersey use a validator with my message interpolator but I'm still trying to understand why I'm not able to inject it with the @Inject annotation in Jersey classes !

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: I also had this problem, which version of Jersey are you using? I ended up just using `@Autowired` inside Jersey controlled classes.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Jersey 2.26-b07 version. It seems to be a beta version handling spring 4 bridge. But I had the same problem with stable Jersey version and Spring 3.

Comment: Haven't tested, but most likely because HK2 services take precedence with @Inject. You can easily test it by also making OtherService a HK2 service. See which one gets injected

Comment: Thanks I'll test that ! But do you have an idea of how this precendance is defined ?